# Why mongoosejs inserts null values when subdocument not passed?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

When child document information is not passed in the mongodb, it inserts an empty array with null object.
I have a user (parent schema) schema in user.js file. This would act as a parent schema which contains user details.

```
mongoose.Schema({
  name:{ type: String ,required: true},
  address:[Address]
})
```

and address schema in another file named address.js this is a child schema which is a part of user schema.

```
mongoose.Schema({
 city: { type: String}
})
```

Now in User schema i want to make address as optional field and default it to empty array when no data is passed while insert operation.

when i do insert with out providing data for child object, the expected document should look like:

```
{
 name:"user111",
 address:[]
}
```

but instead i get it as

```
{
 name:'user111',
 address:[null]
}
```

is it the expected behavior? how to make the schema to allow empty child documents?